# c++ static_cast and references

Tags: c++, static-cast

```
struct A{};
struct B : A{};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A& a_ref = a;

    static_cast<B>(a); // *1
    static_cast<B&>(a_ref); // *2

    return 0;
}
```

(*1) produces an error and i understand why. (*2) compiles fine, but why? And, as long as it compiles and suppose `B` contains some attributes, what if i cast `a_ref` to `B&` and then try to access the attributes? I think i will have an run-time error or something.

So, as i can see, there is a situation which leads to crash and there are no ways to avoid it, unlike with `dynamic_cast` where one can check the result of casting for null or put code in a `try-catch` region. How do i have to deal with such situation where i need to *cast references* and be sure that i really get the right references.

Comment: You have to know what you're doing with `static_cast`, there are no runtime exceptions on wrongly used statically casted results.

Comment: You can use `static_cast` to downcast lvalues to references of derived classes, because there's no implicit cast for that way (as opposed to converting from a derived to a base class). You should only use it for that purpose *if you know beforehand* that it's safe (i.e. that the lvalue you're converting is of the derived type or derived).

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why would you need a reference to the derived type?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I need it exactly for casting A& to B& and work with attributes.

Comment: A compiler will only find certain kinds of problems.  Line `*2` in isolation seems fine, since casting an `A&` to a `B&` would be valid in some situations.  The compiler would have to do more sophisticated analysis to determine that it isn't actually valid in this case.  This may be either too difficult or too slow to be practical.

Comment: @fogbit:  I understand that.  Are you sure your design isn't broken?

Comment: @John Diblin: as long as we don't live in world of unicorns and i'm working on legacy code, of course the desing is broken : -)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From standard n3337 draft 5.2.9/2

> An lvalue of type “cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 D,” where D is a class
> derived (Clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10),
> cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is neither a virtual base class
> of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D.

In your case:

`B` is class derived from `A`, both are non-const, and conversion from `A*` to `B*` is allowed, `A` is not virtual base class of `D`.

Answer (score 6):

`static_cast<>` will only check if the types are compatible

In case 1 types are not directly compatible since the re is no operator to describe the **copy** relation between A and B

In case 2 the cast is a reference cast and as far as the compiler is concerned `A*` can be casted to `B*` because they are compatible. The compiler will not know what the pointer `a_ref` holds so that's why it allows you to use it. `dynamic_cast<>` checks the class the pointer points to also.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the reasons why I use `boost::polymorphic_downcast` ([doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm#Polymorphic_cast)) - in debug it uses `dynamic_cast` followed by assert and in release it is `static_cast`, so no performance hit.

Comment: thanks for the info, i'll check ``boost::polymorphic_downcast``

Answer (score 2):

> (*2) compiles fine, but why?

In general, you can't check the dynamic type statically; and `static_cast` doesn't do any dynamic type checking. It allows any conversion that *might* be valid according to the static types, including conversions that aren't valid according to the dynamic types.

> what if i cast a_ref to B& and then try to access the attributes?

Undefined behaviour. If you use `static_cast`, then the onus is on you to make sure the conversion is valid.

> How do i have to deal with such situation where i need to cast references and be sure that i really get the right references.

For polymorphic types, use `dynamic_cast`. Applied to a reference, it will throw `std::bad_cast` if the conversion is not valid.

For non-polymorphic types, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to highlight the point mentioned in dyp's comment, which is also hinted by Mike Seymour's answer.

Unlike `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` doesn't perform any run-time check about the validity of the casting. If we are sure that a pointer (or reference) to a base class is pointing (or referring) to a derived object, `static_cast` can be safely used to cast it to a pointer (or reference) to the derived type. The attributes of the derived class will be available. In such safe settings, using `static_cast` leads to performance gains compared to using `dynamic_cast`.